# Mark all autoremovable packages as manually-installed in one command

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

I have many packages that are marked as autoremovable. I want to mark them as manually-installed, so that they are no longer autoremovable.

I can do it one package at-a-time using

```
sudo apt-mark manual <package name>
```

But how can I do it for all of the packages in one go, without typing all of the package names.

An answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218161/apt-get-changing-status-of-packages-in-bulk-to-not-automatically-installed) describes how to mark all automatically-installed packages as manually-installed, but I want to mark only the autoremovable packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify multiple package names as arguments to `apt-mark manual`:

```
sudo apt-mark manual package1 package2 package3
```

This will mark all those packages as manually installed.

Thus

```
sudo apt-mark manual $(sudo apt-get -s autoremove 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Remv / { print $2 }')
```

will mark all packages which are auto-removable as manually installed.